# Sharepoint COM works from Silverlight but not from WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I'm running into an interesting situation. I need to access a SharePoint site asset library from both a WPF application and an Silverlight application. My Silverlight application is working 100%, but my WPF application gets a (500) Internal Server Error back from the service.

Silverlight Code:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://myfullyQualifiedName.com");
        clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
        clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
    }

    private void onQuerySucceeded(object sender, ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs args)
    {

    }

    private void onQueryFailed(object sender, ClientRequestFailedEventArgs args)
    {

    }
```

WPF Code:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://myfullyqualifiedname.com/");
        //clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password", "Domain");
        clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

I have tried with and without specifying credentials, either way I get the Internal server error.

Both Silverlight and non Silverlight Sharepoint client DLL's that I use has is version 14.4762.1000.

Now if I change the URL to one of our other sites, the WPF Code works flawlessly. So I think it must be a SharePoint settings somewhere.

Comment: I suggest that you don't abbreviate Client Object Model as "COM". COM is much more likely to be understood as "Component Object Model".

Answer (score 1):

Solved !! Why WPF Authentication wouldn't work when Silverlight works. (WPF was trying to use Kerberos, Silverlight was using NTLM) - Simple fix:

```
ClientContext _clientContext = new ClientContext(sharePointSiteUrl);
Web _web = _clientContext.Web;

_clientContext.Load(_web, website => website.Title);
_clientContext.Load(_web.Webs);

CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add(new Uri(sharePointSiteUrl), "NTLM", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
_clientContext.Credentials = cc;
_clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
ListCollection _listCollection = _web.Lists;
```